# Ruby hash pattern matching - optional pattern

Tags: ruby, pattern-matching

With Ruby 3 hash pattern matching, is it possible to specify that the `rest` contains only allowed keys?
So far I only came up with this:

```
opts = { value: 5, limit: 10 } # valid
# opts = { value: 5 } # valid
# opts = { value: 5, foo: 10 } # not valid

case opts
in value:, **rest if rest.nil? || (rest.keys - %i[limit]).empty?
end
```

Something inspired by Flowtype might be `in value:, limit?:` or even
`in value: Integer, limit?: Integer`

Answer (score 4):

Note that `rest.nil?` will never be `true` in your example, so you don't need that part at all:

```
case opts
in value:, **rest if (rest.keys - %i[limit]).empty?
end

# or if you are using rails
case opts
in value:, **rest if rest.excluding(:limit).empty?
end
```

`**rest` is always a Hash.

---

There is no pattern matching equivalent to what you're trying to do, this is as close as I could get using alternate patterns:

```rb
opts = {value: 5, limit: 10}
case opts
in value:, **rest if rest in {limit:_}|{}
  [value, rest]
end

#=> [5, {:limit=>10}]
```

```rb
opts = {value: 5}
case opts
in value:, **rest if rest in {limit:_}|{}
  [value, rest]
end

#=> [5, {}]
```

```rb
opts = {value: 5, foo: 1}
case opts
in value:, **rest if rest in {limit:_}|{}
  [value, rest]
end

#=> (irb):346:in `<main>': {:value=>5, :foo=>1}: guard clause does not return true (NoMatchingPatternError)
```

Comment: That guard clause with a pattern match is interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the question but you can specify multiple patterns for instance:

```
options = [{ value: 5, limit: 10 }, 
        { value: 5 },
        { value: 5, foo: 10 }]

outputs = options.map do |opts| 
  {opts: opts,
   matched: case opts
    in {value: Integer, **nil} 
      'matched value'
    in {value: Integer, limit: Integer, **nil}
      'matched value and limit'
    else 
      'no match'
  end}
end

#=> [{:opts=>{:value=>5, :limit=>10}, :matched=>"matched value and limit"}, 
#    {:opts=>{:value=>5}, :matched=>"matched value"}, 
#    {:opts=>{:value=>5, :foo=>10}, :matched=>"no match"}]
```

Which seems to meet the request.

For reference `**nil` means "and no other keys".

Comment: Yes, this works, but only if there's only one optional key, if there are more, there would be too many branches. I guess then the only way would be to use `**rest` and `slice` it later (e.g. to use as kwargs to another method), without being able to have a value pattern on individual item.

Comment: @stanley90 maybe you can specify a use case and we can propose alternate options to solve this issue (likely not involving pattern matching based on your comment).

Comment: Actually I just wanted to be strict about forwarding optional arguments to another method (extract the positional arguments, follow the rest, but only the valid keys), but I think it's not really worth the effort.

Comment: @stanley90 in that case if you really wanted to pursue that I would capture the positional and then just use `slice` to pull the valid keys from `**rest`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77728293/ruby-short-cut-for-passing-only-expected-number-of-arguments-to-a-lambda/77729060#77729060) is a way to do that using a lambda but could easily be adapted to use a method instead.